# Best way to send CSV data from AWS S3 to external source (with batches)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Looking for the best way to send data from AWS S3 to external source.
I have CSV file ~4Gb size.

For now, I am trying to create Lambda function to parse CSV in batches to send it, it looks like:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io

...
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='...)

for chunk in pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), encoding='utf8', chunksize=1000000, low_memory=False):
    send_function()
...
```

But for now, I have an error:

> [ERROR] MemoryError
> Traceback (most recent call last): ...

Looks like something wrong in my code or CSV file is too large...

So, my question is: is it a good way to implement it (as I described above) or maybe you can advise somethin better, maybe I should use some other AWS service instead Lambda?

Comment: Is it just a single csv file, or you have to do it automatically on multiple occasions when new csv files are uploaded to the bucket?

Comment: @Marcin CSV file - it is a result of AWS Athena query to parse and get only necessary information

Comment: Just file, then this is really bad choice and if you have to transfer the csv data with in a specific way, then reduce the chunk size to use lower memory or increase the maximum memory of the lambda.